# Google Analytics query: landing page and page paths

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am a newbie with SQL and BigQuery so I had hoped you could help me with a standard SQL query I am working on.

The data set is from a Google Analytics roll-up property.
The objective with this query is to have for each session: the date, the GA property, the number of transactions, the total revenue, some custom dimensions that are session-scoped and 2 other elements I can't seem to grasp.

1) I would like to add the landing page for each session. There are some resources on the internet for that but so far I didn't succeed. Do you have any idea ?

2) I also would like to add funnel steps based on page paths, like have a column "Step 1" where it indicates 1 or 0 depending if the session contains a page view on a certain page path or not. Do you have any idea on how to do that ?

This is my current query (sorry if it's not well formatted):

```
SELECT
  date,
  visitId,
  hits.sourcePropertyInfo.sourcePropertyDisplayName AS service,
  totals.transactions AS transactions,
  totals.totalTransactionRevenue AS revenue,
ARRAY(
SELECT STRUCT(
  MAX(IF(cd.index=3, cd.value, NULL)) AS endUserProvider,
  MAX(IF(cd.index=2, cd.value, NULL)) AS connection,
  MAX(IF(cd.index=10, cd.value, NULL)) AS sid,
  MAX(IF(cd.index=11, cd.value, NULL)) AS price,
  MAX(IF(cd.index=12, cd.value, NULL)) AS period,
  MAX(IF(cd.index=13, cd.value, NULL)) AS serviceId,
  MAX(IF(cd.index=14, cd.value, NULL)) AS promotion) 
FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions) cd) result
FROM `wide-oasis-135923.126764585.ga_sessions_*`,
UNNEST(hits) hits
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = '20171026'
LIMIT 100;
```

Thank you very much

Comment: That query is not standard (ANSI/ISO) SQL. Change to a better tag.

Comment: Jarhl is right. That query is far from being "standard SQL". There is no `if`, `struct` or `limit` in standard SQL. And those dreaded backticks are also invalid in standard SQL.

Comment: hello @a_horse_with_no_name and Jarlh, thank you for your comments. I don't understand. From the Big Query documentation, it seems like LIMIT clauses are valid. (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#limit-clause-and-offset-clause) And it's the same for backticks. BigQuery indicates " If this is a table identifier, escape the name with ` e.g. ` table.name ` rather than [table.name]." About the IF, how would you get data from custom dimensions then ?

Comment: Those things might be valid for BigQuery, but they are **not** valid in standard ANSI SQL.

Comment: I see, but as I am using BigQuery, I should use SQL syntax from their documentation. I cannot use standard ANSI SQL if it's not the same in BigQuery.

Comment: Yeah. Backticks are supported by multiple databases (including the popular MySQL) - I don't see why not tag this query as `SQL`. But maybe that tag is just bringing a lot of unwanted attention and no actual help.